# MYSQL - update values that may or may not be NULL

Tags: mysql

I've got a query that needs to update a value that may or may not be null.  The query I'm currently working with is:

```
UPDATE
    t1
LEFT JOIN
    t2 ON t1.a = t2.a AND t2.b = 1000
SET
    t1.c = CONCAT(t2.c, ' ', t1.c)
WHERE
    (
        t1.c IS NULL
        OR t1.c NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.c , '%')
    )
    AND t2.c != ''
    AND t2.c IS NOT NULL
```

This query will not update any null values, though it will correctly update other qualified values.  Any thoughts?

Comment: i'm getting the suspicion that it's `AND t2.c IS NOT NULL`. this part will filter out any anything where `t2.c` is NULL even if `t1.a` and `t2.a` have a match.

Comment: @Memor-X Thanks for the thought - just tried removing that.  Jeremy - not sure if you're responding to me - but I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Adition

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  Turns out I needed a `CASE WHEN` for setting the value because t1.c can be `NULL`